# htaccess redirect path to pdf

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a directory called `/manuals` which contains multiple PDF files.

What I'd like to achieve is to redirect and append a pdf extension to any URL which accesses this directory like so:

```
https://website.com/manuals/FM0100 to https://website.com/manuals/FM0100.pdf
```

Is this possible in a .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, of course that is possible. (Before you ask for code now, please go read [ask]. URL rewriting is an already massively broad documented and discussed topic, so you should make an _attempt_ yourself here first of all.)

Answer (score 2):

In the `/manuals/.htaccess` file (ie. *inside* the `/manuals` subdirectory) you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Append ".pdf" to any request that does not already have a file extension.
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.pdf [R=302,L]
```

The request is externally redirected with a 302 - temporary - redirect.

Alternatively, you could *internally rewrite* the request (ie. `.pdf` extension hidden from user) by removing the `R=302` flag.

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting I found a solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} manuals
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !jpg
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.pdf

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This could be simplified quite a bit. Your conditions are rather too general as they match _anywhere_ in the URL, rather than at the start or end of the requested URL. I've added an answer.